# Google Play In-App Review API - Error posting review

Tags: android, google-play-core

I'm using Google Play In-App Review API to display in-app native review window. The window itself opens fine. However once user actually clicks "send review" the window closes with the following error:

> Error while retrieving information from server. DF-DFERH-01

This error can be found in other questions, however the solution is always to "clear cache" or other client-side errors. But this error is present for all my users, not just for me.

From ADB:

```
03-26 15:32:20.973 22692 22747 E Volley  : [1211] dua.a: Unexpected response code 400 for https://play-fe.googleapis.com/fdfe/addReview?doc=tech.alloutfun.pvppuzzle&title=&content=jsjj&rating=5&itpr=false&rst=1
03-26 15:32:20.974 22692 22692 E Finsky  : [1] qmi.b(2): Error posting review: network time: 0, HTTP status code: na, exception DisplayErrorMessage[Error while retrieving information from server. DF-DFERH-01]
```

Also:

```
03-26 15:32:07.215 22692 22742 D Volley  : [1205] dua.a: HTTP response for request=<[ ] https://play-fe.googleapis.com/fdfe/allowInAppReview?doc=tech.alloutfun.pvppuzzle 0x4be64f9b NORMAL 104> [lifetime=3385], [size=52], [rc=200], [retryCount=0]
03-26 15:32:07.244 22692 22726 I System.out: Caught a exception encoding the public key: com.android.apksig.internal.asn1.Asn1DecodingException: Failed to parse dqi.a
03-26 15:32:07.244 22692 22726 W System.err: com.android.apksig.internal.asn1.Asn1DecodingException: Failed to parse dqi.a
03-26 15:32:07.245 22692 22726 W System.err:    at dpt.h(PG:13)
03-26 15:32:07.245 22692 22726 W System.err:    at dpt.f(Unknown Source:1)
03-26 15:32:07.245 22692 22726 W System.err:    at dpt.d(PG:11)
03-26 15:32:07.245 22692 22726 W System.err:    at dpt.b(PG:4)
03-26 15:32:07.246 22692 22726 W System.err:    at dpk.e(PG:3)
03-26 15:32:07.246 22692 22726 W System.err:    at kyh.T(PG:41)
03-26 15:32:07.246 22692 22726 W System.err:    at kyh.l(PG:10)
03-26 15:32:07.246 22692 22726 W System.err:    at rfa.j(PG:16)
03-26 15:32:07.246 22692 22726 W System.err:    at rfa.i(PG:24)
03-26 15:32:07.246 22692 22726 W System.err:    at jpn.call(PG:81)
03-26 15:32:07.246 22692 22726 W System.err:    at affd.a(Unknown Source:2)
03-26 15:32:07.246 22692 22726 W System.err:    at afei.run(PG:3)
03-26 15:32:07.246 22692 22726 W System.err:    at affe.run(Unknown Source:4)
03-26 15:32:07.246 22692 22726 W System.err:    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
03-26 15:32:07.246 22692 22726 W System.err:    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
03-26 15:32:07.246 22692 22726 W System.err:    at ili.run(PG:14)
03-26 15:32:07.246 22692 22726 W System.err:    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:929)
03-26 15:32:07.246 22692 22726 W System.err: Caused by: com.android.apksig.internal.asn1.Asn1BerParser$Asn1UnexpectedTagException: Tag mismatch. Expected: UNIVERSAL BIT STRING, but found UNIVERSAL SEQUENCE
03-26 15:32:07.246 22692 22726 W System.err:    at dpr.a(PG:2)
03-26 15:32:07.246 22692 22726 W System.err:    at dpt.h(PG:11)
03-26 15:32:07.246 22692 22726 W System.err:    ... 16 more
03-26 15:32:07.250 22692 22726 I System.out: Caught a exception encoding the public key: com.android.apksig.internal.asn1.Asn1DecodingException: Failed to parse dqi.a
03-26 15:32:07.250 22692 22726 W System.err: com.android.apksig.internal.asn1.Asn1DecodingException: Failed to parse dqi.a
03-26 15:32:07.250 22692 22726 W System.err:    at dpt.h(PG:13)
03-26 15:32:07.250 22692 22726 W System.err:    at dpt.f(Unknown Source:1)
03-26 15:32:07.250 22692 22726 W System.err:    at dpt.d(PG:11)
03-26 15:32:07.250 22692 22726 W System.err:    at dpt.b(PG:4)
03-26 15:32:07.250 22692 22726 W System.err:    at dpk.e(PG:3)
03-26 15:32:07.250 22692 22726 W System.err:    at bwg.i(PG:33)
03-26 15:32:07.250 22692 22726 W System.err:    at bwg.d(PG:9)
03-26 15:32:07.250 22692 22726 W System.err:    at rfa.j(PG:12)
03-26 15:32:07.250 22692 22726 W System.err:    at rfa.i(PG:27)
03-26 15:32:07.250 22692 22726 W System.err:    at jpn.call(PG:81)
03-26 15:32:07.250 22692 22726 W System.err:    at affd.a(Unknown Source:2)
03-26 15:32:07.250 22692 22726 W System.err:    at afei.run(PG:3)
03-26 15:32:07.250 22692 22726 W System.err:    at affe.run(Unknown Source:4)
03-26 15:32:07.250 22692 22726 W System.err:    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
03-26 15:32:07.250 22692 22726 W System.err:    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
03-26 15:32:07.250 22692 22726 W System.err:    at ili.run(PG:14)
03-26 15:32:07.250 22692 22726 W System.err:    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:929)
03-26 15:32:07.250 22692 22726 W System.err: Caused by: com.android.apksig.internal.asn1.Asn1BerParser$Asn1UnexpectedTagException: Tag mismatch. Expected: UNIVERSAL BIT STRING, but found UNIVERSAL SEQUENCE
03-26 15:32:07.251 22692 22726 W System.err:    at dpr.a(PG:2)
03-26 15:32:07.251 22692 22726 W System.err:    at dpt.h(PG:11)
03-26 15:32:07.251 22692 22726 W System.err:    ... 16 more
```

I'm using Unity 2020.3.2f1. Tried with R8 and custom "com.google.android.*" provided proguard config files, does not work. Turning off all minification does not make a difference, either. I've added Google.Play libraries to link.xml. Build is uploaded and installed though Google Play Internal Testing.

I have no idea what to even try next. Issue on Google Issue Tracker was closed (Won't fix, Infeasible) without further comment.

Answer (score 1):

There's a commonly accepted answer here by HanSoloYolo that isn't client-side related: https://forum.unity.com/threads/google-play-services-not-working.485322/#post-3210077

The instructions likely need updating from the old post, I can see an app signing key certificate in the Play Console in `Setup` -> `App integrity` that may be the SHA-1 you need.

Comment: This did not resolve the issue, the behavior is the same and the exception logged in adb is the same.

Comment: Hm, judging from the error message it looks as though your initial setup got corrupted. Perhaps try running through the Play Core setup steps again? Also worth checking if a later Unity version fixes the issue. You could also file an issue here: https://github.com/google/play-unity-plugins/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen